# Error message does not send (MissingPermissions, CommandNotFound)

Tags: python, discord.py

import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Errors(commands.Cog):

```
def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_ready(self):
    print ('Cog loaded: errors.py')

    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def command_not_found(self, ctx, error):
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title='**DEVELOPER**', description='Error occured:\n error.CommandNotFound', color=7419530)
    embedVar.add_field(name='**NOT PARSED**', value='Could not find command.')

    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_permission_error(self, ctx, error):
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title='**DEVELOPER**', description='Error occured:\n error.MissingPermissions', color=7419530)
    embedVar.add_field(name='**NOT PARSED**', value='Missing required permissions.')

    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
```

def setup(client):
client.add_cog(Errors(client))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't handle errors like that... Those events do not exist. To handle errors you use the `on_command_error` event:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
   if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        # code for `CommandNotFound`
   elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I thought the event was changeable haha.

Comment: No, not really. Remember to accept the answer if it helped.